# Error: cannot find name ionViewDidLeave

Tags: view, navigation, ionic2, event-listener

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with ionViewDidLeave. I'm getting an error from the terminal that says "cannot find name ionViewDidLeave". Is there something I have to import to use it? I have already imported the navController.

Here is my

**ts.file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EditPost } from '../edit-post/edit-post';

import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class Home {

     buttonColor: string = '#787083'; 


  constructor (public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public loading: LoadingController) {


//OTHER FUNCTIONS

    /*Navigate to edit page */

    editPost(){
      this.buttonColor = '#553481'; //change button background color on click 
           this.navCtrl.push(EditPost, {})
            .catch(() => {
                // Page requires authentication, re-direct to Login page
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(Login, {routeToPage: 'EditPost'});

            });

            ionViewDidLeave(){

        this.buttonColor = '#787083';

           }; 

    }// end of editPost()

}//close class
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-footer class="footer">
  <ion-segment small class="footer">
                    <ion-segment-button id="post" value="post" (click)="postEvent()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': buttonColor}" small> <span class="footer">NEW POST</span></ion-segment-button>
                    <ion-segment-button  id="edit" value="edit"  (click)="editPost()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': buttonColor}" small> <span class="footer">Edit Post</span></ion-segment-button > 
  </ion-segment>
 </ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write inside an method

```
ionViewDidLeave()
```

you are calling a function from the current scope (editPost) function. The right way to call from the object would be:

```
this.ionViewDidLeave()
```

but I guess it's not right to call it (ionViewDidLeave is part of Ionic's page lifecycle), and I guess too that what you want to do is define this method and you have a type in your code. The right code should be:

```
export class Home {

    buttonColor: string = '#787083'; 

    constructor (public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public loading: LoadingController) {

    editPost(){
      this.buttonColor = '#553481'; //change button background color on click 
           this.navCtrl.push(EditPost, {})
            .catch(() => {
                // Page requires authentication, re-direct to Login page
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(Login, {routeToPage: 'EditPost'});
            });

    }// end of editPost()


    ionViewDidLeave(){

      this.buttonColor = '#787083';

    };

}//close class
```